# Splitting a large XML file in two using C# console app

Tags: c#, xml, file, console-application

I need to split am XML file (~400 MB) in two, so that a legacy app can process the file. At the moment its throwing an exception when the file is over around 300 MB.

As I can't change the app which is doing the processing, I thought I could write a console app to split the file in two first. What's the best way of doing this? It needs to be automated so I can't use a text editor, and I'm using C#.

I suppose the considerations are:

- writing a header to the new files after the split
- finding a good place to split (not in middle of 'object')
- closing off tags and file correctly in first file, opening tags correctly in second file

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "best" way is likely to be based on [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) and [`XmlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx). Using these "streaming" APIs avoids needing to load the whole XML object model in memory (and with DOM –[`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)– that can need considerably more memory than the text data).

Using these APIs is harder than just loading the document: your implementation needs to track the context (eg. current node and ancestor list), but in this case that wouldn't be complex (just enough to open the elements to the current state when opening each output document).

Comment: Yeah thanks, I thought a stream would be a good option, I was just put off a bit by having the overhead of where I was in document, so was just checking if there was another option.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider making a full copy of the file and then deleting elements from each.  You will have to decide at what level the deletions could occur.

It should then be fairly straightforward, from a count of how many elements have been deleted from FileA, to identify how many (and from what starting point) should be deleted from FileB.

Is that feasible for your circumstance?

I have put together the following to describe my thinking.  It is not tested, but I would value the comments of the group.  Downvote me if you want but I would prefer constructive criticism.

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SplitXML(args[0], args[1]);
        }

        private static void SplitXML(string fileNameA, string fileNameB)
        {
            int deleteCount;
            XmlNodeList childNodes;
            XmlReader reader;
            XmlTextWriter writer;
            XmlDocument doc;

            // ------------- Process FileA
            reader = XmlReader.Create(fileNameA);
            doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(reader);

            childNodes = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
            deleteCount = childNodes.Count / 2;

            for (int i = 0; i < deleteCount; i++)
            {
                doc.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(childNodes.Item(0));
            }
            writer = new XmlTextWriter("FileC", null);
            doc.Save(writer);

            // ------------- Process FileB
            reader = XmlReader.Create(fileNameB);
            doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(reader);

            childNodes = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;

            for (int i = deleteCount + 1; i < childNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                doc.DocumentElement.RemoveChild(childNodes.Item(deleteCount +1));
            }
            writer = new XmlTextWriter("FileD", null);
            doc.Save(writer);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an easier implementation. It will save you the trouble of opening and closing any tags that would get cut off.

Comment: May I have the Poster's / group's permission to post a code sample ?  The reason I ask is because I am no c# guru and would really value some harsh criticism.

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. I ended up using an XmlTextWriter without creating a copy of the file. It was an interesting suggestion but if the files were really huge copying might use alot of space before the processing starts.

Comment: Agreed.  The approach was intended to be conceptually simple - that's the kind of programmer I am ;)

Answer (score 0):

If it's pure C#, running it as a 64-bit process might solve the problem for no effort at all (assuming you have a 64-bit Windows at hand).

Comment: Its his legacy application that is causing the problem

Comment: Legacy apps can't be written in C#?

Comment: Yeah you're right the legacy app is C#, but I can't change that at all, and its 32-bit.

Comment: @Marcelo - Yes but the poster stated in his question he could not change it.

Comment: Often, a C# assembly built as 32-bit doesn't actually have to be run as 32-bit. You can use the CorFlags conversion tool to clear the 32-bit flag and see if it successfully runs as a 64-bit process. If it contains any native code, this won't work, but it'll take all of five minutes to give it a go.

Comment: @Hugh: Sometimes people think they are operating under constraints that aren't real. I'm trying to suggest an alternative that may or may not work, but will take very little effort to test.

Comment: Could be worth a try. I'll check if this would be possible to test.

Comment: I agree its definitely a good idea to look for the most straightforward solution, which in this case would be fix the app reading in the xml. In some cases though this won't be possible, so it'd be nice to know any suggestions for splitting the file anyway (incase a fix to the consuming app works at this file size but not if it gets alot bigger or something).

Comment: @Marcelo - point taken.  I made the wrong assumption that the legacy code was not available to the poster.  You were right.